# IOS Spacing for SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I wish for the svg to not have this weird small "margin" on the left and right, and it only happens on my iPad pro. I have already added the two transform lines to make similar margins disappear from my iphone. So, this issue currently only occurs on my iPad pro and not my iPhone or my desktop.

I have two other svg's that serve the same purpose (a wave on the screen) and created from the same generator that do not have this issue, even on iPad.

I have tried display: block or width: 100% and those two does not work.

This is the SVG code:

```
<img class="wave" src="/assets/svg/about_below.svg">
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.wave{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    transform: scale(1);
    display: block;
}
```

[image]